# Consecutive, conflicting regex substitutions

Tags: python, regex

I've tried this for the italics:

```
r = re.compile(r"(\*[^ ]+\*)")
r.sub(r'<i>"\1"</i>', foo)
```

but it doesn't work, as I am sure anyone in the regex know will see right away.

Comment: regexps are particularly bad for this sort of task generally because they are never exactly the amount of greedy that you want. In your specific case of a single word you'll be okay, but if you are trying to reinvent Markdown you'll need a real parser, and regexps are not parsers (even though so many people want them to be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex and substitution need a few tweaks.

```
r = re.compile(r"(\*[^ ]+\*)")
```

You are capturing a bit too much here -- the asterisks are preserved in `\1`.

```
r.sub(r'<i>"\1"</i>', foo)
```

You are substituting a bit too much here -- the double-quote marks are included in the substitution.  Example:

```
r.sub(r'<i>"\1"</i>', '*foo*')  # -> '<i>"*foo*"</i>'
```

Try something like this:

```
foo = '***foo***'
bold = re.compile(r'''\*\*([^ ]+)\*\*''')
ital = re.compile(r'''\*([^ ]+)\*''')

ital.sub(r'''<i>\1</i>''', bold.sub(r'''<b>\1</b>''', foo)) # '<b><i>foo</i></b>'
```

Answer (score 2):

It would easily work, if you switch the order of substitutions. Handling the bold case first would prevent italics taking over.